# PostgreSQL: Como selecionar um campo baseado no valor máximo de outro campo?

Tags: postgresql, select, timestamp

Tenho uma tabela com a seguinte configuração:

```
create table baixas_do_requerimento as
codigo_requerimento text,
tipo_baixa text,
data_baixa timestamp
```

Cada `código_requerimento` pode repetir inúmeras vezes, ou seja, pode ter várias baixas de tipos e datas diferentes.

Exemplos de dados:

| codigo_requerimento | tipo_baixa | data_baixa |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123abc | P | 2019-03-05 |
| 123abc | P | 2020-01-25 |
| 123abc | T | 2020-06-15 |

Preciso fazer uma view onde eu seleciono o `codigo_requerimento`, a data da primeira baixa, a data da última baixa e o tipo da última baixa.

O resultado esperado é:

| codigo_requerimento | primeira_baixa | ultima_baixa | tipo_ultima_baixa |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123abc | 2019-03-05 | 2020-06-15 | T |

Comecei da seguinte forma:

```
create materialized view resumo_baixas as
select
codigo_requerimento,
min(data_baixa) as primeira_baixa,
max(data_baixa) as ultima_baixa,
(...)
group by codigo_requerimento
```

Preciso trazer também o tipo de baixa da última baixa, e não estou conseguindo pensar numa forma de fazer isso.

Alguma luz?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Opção 1: Subconsulta**

Faça uma subconsulta, usando os valores encontrados na primeira:

```
SELECT
    codigo_requerimento,
    MIN(data_baixa) as primeira_baixa,
    MAX(data_baixa) as ultima_baixa,
    (SELECT tipo_baixa FROM baixas_do_requerimento WHERE codigo_requerimento = A.codigo_requerimento AND data_baixa = MAX(A.data_baixa) LIMIT 1) AS tipo_ultima_baixa
FROM
     baixas_do_requerimento A
GROUP BY
     codigo_requerimento
```

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/4jyoMCicNSZpjMt4jFYoz5/1450

**Edit - Opção 2: Window Functions**

Talvez esta alternativa usando [Window Functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/tutorial-window.html) tenha melhor performance:

```
SELECT
    B.*
FROM
    (SELECT
        codigo_requerimento,
        MIN(data_baixa) OVER (PARTITION BY codigo_requerimento) AS primeira_baixa,
        MAX(data_baixa) OVER (PARTITION BY codigo_requerimento) AS ultima_baixa,
        FIRST_VALUE(tipo_baixa) OVER (PARTITION BY codigo_requerimento ORDER BY data_baixa DESC) AS tipo_ultima_baixa
    FROM
        baixas_do_requerimento A
    ) B
GROUP BY
    codigo_requerimento, primeira_baixa, ultima_baixa, tipo_ultima_baixa
ORDER BY
    codigo_requerimento ASC
```

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/qUCE45Buh97AuAq6fFzTUH/1

Comment: Obrigada Eduardo, pela luz! Funcionou aqui! Aumentou consideravelmente o tempo de consulta, mas prefiro ter a informação do que perder ela.

Comment: @ClaraMagalhaes infelizmente esta é uma desvantagem da subconsulta. Apenas para teste, você pode criar um indice usando os campos (codigo_requerimento, data_baixa) para ver se a performance melhora.

Comment: @ClaraMagalhaes coloquei uma solução alternativa, poderia dizer se a performance foi melhor ou pior? Gostaria de saber com dados reais.